# window.open for Google Maps - Gray Screen on iPhone Google Chrome

Tags: jquery, iphone, google-chrome

I have a link my users can click on that will open up a google map location in a new tab using the below url:

https://www.google.com/maps?q=123%20W%20Main%20St.%20Dallas%20Texas

I use jQuery to open the new tab with:

```
$(document).on('click','a',function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var hrefValue = $(this).attr('href');
  window.open(hrefValue,'_blank');
});
```

This works fine with desktop users and iPhone Safari users. But on iPhone Google Chrome if you have the Google Maps app installed, it will open the Google Maps app (which is fine), and if you go back to the website, it will display a gray screen (not fine). I can fix this by selecting the 'Tab' icon (which will not show a new tab, only the tabs I've had open already) and selecting the same tab again. Any way around this?

You can see this working here:
https://jsfiddle.net/fnexq36n/2/

My environment:

- iPhone 5s (iOS v9.3.2)
- Google Chrome (Latest)
- Google Maps (Latest)

Comment: Because I was unable to post two links, here is the screenshot of the issue:
http://i.imgur.com/Z55iee2.png

Comment: why don't you just add target attribute without using jQuery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the same exact problem in php code and the problem goes away when I change the line below

```
<a target="_blank" href="http://maps.google.com/maps?q=$latitude,$longitude"> $street $city $country </a> </br></br>"
```

to

```
<a  href="http://maps.google.com/maps?q=$latitude,$longitude"> $street $city $country </a> </br></br>"
```

Removing `target="_blank"` helps but the problem is on desktop it doesn't open new tab. On iphone, it opens google maps app.

If you remove `_blank` in your code, that might work too.